# Check Facebook content for public / private setting

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm attempting to use Facebook's Graph API to detect whether or not certain posts that appear on my site are set to public / private on Facebook. The aim is to prevent the user from posting Facebook content to my site if they are including a link that is NOT set to 'Public'.

I've looked over the documentation but it is very sketchy and unclear. There doesn't seem to be a solid explanation anywhere as to how to detect privacy settings of a post/photo/video etc using the JavaScript SDK.

This is the unclear documentation that I have read through:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.1/url

My attempt thus far:

```
FB.api(
    "/{I've included post id's here, but haven't received a response?}",
    function (response) {
      if (response && !response.error) {
          alert("Success")
      }
    }
);
```

I did read on a similar question that if no response is given from the code above, then it would mean that the post/photo/video is not public, meaning that it must be set to private. The issue is that I HAVE included public post id's within the above code, and that I am not receiving a response from them, leaving me a little confused.

If anyone could shed some light on the matter it'd be much appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Use `console.log(response)` as first statement in your callback function, and then go check what the object _actually_ contains.

Comment: Why do you want to do this? And what do you mean with posts to "your site"? It is not possible to get the privacy-level of comments. Also, finding an other way to detect it might not be conform the policy, e.g. if you want to incentive people of posting public comments.